# How likely is it that this chip was damaged?

Tags: voltage, memory, flash

I am trying to use a dataflash memory that requires a voltage of 2.7 to 3.6. Before I was supplying it with too little voltage. Then I supplied it with 5V. Could either of these cause damage to the chip?

The part number is W25P80 and the datasheet is [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://www.winbond-usa.com/products/Nexflash/pdfs/datasheets/W25P80-16-32j.pdf&rct=j&q=w25p80&ei=NQqATey_Jom4sAOv8O2LBg&usg=AFQjCNFT2z5X1gOzmX0E8e4tOy5Yk--7Pg&sig2=moEsAdtGSQcW0DxBkXEDhQ&cad=rja).

Comment: You really should put the part number and link to the data sheet.

Comment: Alright, I edited my post.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

That's what the "absolute maximum ratings" part of the data sheet is for.

Comment: For the supply voltage it says -0.6 to +4.0. So how likely is it?

Comment: The longer you exceed the maximum ratings for and by what degree determine the damage caused. Each chip is different.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

5V may have killed the chip. Too little voltage will make the chip's behaviour unpredictable, but won't harm it (though low voltage during write/erase might damage the data).